# In XCode, how do I see a list of class instances and their number of references?

Tags: xcode

I need to manage memory correctly, so I need to see a list of `User` objects (preferably in readable format) and the references attached to them.

If this is not possible, is there some code I can write to tell my console to print the references out?

Comment: Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/